# Gitlab downstream pipeline for multiple projects is not triggering based on $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

### EDIT #1 and answer:
It was a typo in job definition.

GitLab Enterprise Edition v16.1.3-ee

I have two jobs, first (`local_job`) with such rule:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "pipeline"
```

another one with opposite definition (let's call it `triggered_job`):

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"
```

Obviously the first one must be running on MR and the second one, `triggered_job` only when triggered from another project.

None is triggering from multiple-project trigger when I have $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE variable checked:

```
.trigger_in_another_repo: &trigger_in_another_repo
  stage: trigger_elsewhere
  trigger:
    project: 'test-group/project-name'
    branch: 'test-branch' # change to main after the tests

trigger_in_turbot_repo:
  when: on_success
  <<: *trigger_in_another_repo
```

Nothing triggers or when I set rule for `local_job` to `when: always` without any conditions, it's triggering `local_job` only, so downstream pipeline is working as should. I've added some debugging to the script part of `local_job` and it has presented that `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` was `pipeline` indeed. Here is **copied** fragment of this debug:

```
$ echo "CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE:$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE"
CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE:pipeline
```

So variable has this value "pipeline", but it seem's it's not accessible in this `IF`? But it's following [**Gitlab docs**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#use-rules-to-control-downstream-pipeline-jobs):

```
job1:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"
  script: echo "This job runs in multi-project pipelines only"
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: It was a typo. I think this might be useful for future folks developing multiple project pipelines, as it presents some definition how to trigger such.